# Keyless Signature Infrastructrue ( KSI ) Token Verification

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin, merkle-tree

So I was reading about the **KSI blockchain** but the resources that I have explored on the Internet were not enough to clear up some questions in my mind which are still bothering me!

**Questions:**

Whenever a **customer** requests to **participate** in the **ksi blockchain** then he submits the **hash** of his data to the **ksi gateway**. Then in return he gets a **token**, which is basically a **proof** of his **participation**.
What exactly does this **token contain**?

Through his token he can later on **verify** his data **integrity** as the token **contains** path in the **Merkle tree** from his **leaf node** and way up to the **hash** in the **calendar ledger**. 
How is this path **attached** to the **token** exactly, and how is it **computed**?

Is it first computed at the **ledger level** and then passed down the **aggregation** networks and then to the **requestor**?

Comment: I have removed my other questions as asked by you @CollinD .. I will ask them on a different post!

Comment: Best of luck, I hope that helps to attract more answerers.

Comment: I know the answer to this question now, but i don't think i'm allowed to answer my own question. So, I'll give the answer in the comment!

Comment: Ans  token contains the hash values of the siblings and the order in which they appear , i.e, either left or right.  To recompute the path only these values are sufficient and these hash values of the sibling are passed down from up to down direction i.e, from core cluster -> aggregators -> gateway.

Comment: You are definitely invited to answer your own question if you've found a solution! https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer